# R- Return non matching Product in Merge

Tags: r

I have two csv files with large data. I know hot to merge two csv when data matches, here i am trying to merge but in my output column I am trying to get all products for which Cross Ref and key don't matches.

File 1

```
GROUP   Cross Ref
A1        W123
A2        W123
A3        W123
A4        W123
A5        W123
A6        W123
B1        W124
B2        W124
B3       W124
B4       W124
B5       W124

file 2
Key     Product
W123    y234
W123    764F
W123    Y654
W123    U341
W123    I65F
W123    O654
W124    342
W124    Y6TR
W124    HR34
W124    QW12
W124    675R
```

output Required:

```
Cross Ref   GROUP   Product
W123         A1      342
W123         A1      Y6TR
W123         A1       HR34
W123         A1      QW12
W123         A1      675R
W123         A2      342
W123         A2     Y6TR
W123         A2     HR34
W123         A2     QW12
W123         A2     675R
W123         A3     342
W123         A3     Y6TR
W123         A3     HR34
W123         A3     QW12
W123         A3     675R
```

I tried

```
merge(file1,file2,by.x = "Cross.Ref",by.y = "key",all=T)
```

This is giving me products where both key matches but i need the other one as shown in output file.

Comment: Try adding `all = T` inside your merge

Comment: @camille..I tried all=T, but this don't works.

Comment: So you don't really want to merge on Cross.Ref and Key? Because the first line of your output has Cross.Ref W123, but the Product is assigned to Key W124 in your file2? I think you need to clarify your question a little bit more

Comment: @Kath...yes I want to merge where cross ref and key don't matches, exactly as shown in output.

Comment: Is that only partial output? I'd expect W124 B1 764F there, for example. Fwiw, I am looking at `library(data.table); setDT(DF2); DF2[, CJ(Key = Key, Product = Product, unique=TRUE)][!DF2, on=names(DF2)][DF1, on=.(Key = Cross_Ref), allow.cart = TRUE]`

Comment: @Yes Frank..this is partiall output..It will do the same for W124 as you thought..

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**
The most efficient way is proposed in the comment by @Frank:

```
 library(data.table)
 df12 <- data.frame(GROUP = c("A1","A2","A3"),
                      CrossRef = c("W123", "W124", "W125"), 
                      stringsAsFactors=F)
 df22 <- data.frame(Key = c(rep("W123", 2), rep("W124",2), rep("W125",2)), 
                       Product = c("y234", "764F","Y654","U341","I65F","O654"), 
                       stringsAsFactors=F)

setDT(df22); 
setDT(df12);
df22[, CJ(Key = Key, 
          Product = Product, 
          unique=TRUE)][!df22, on=names(df22)][df12, on=.(Key = CrossRef), allow.cart = TRUE] 
#     Key Product GROUP
# 1: W123    I65F    A1
# 2: W123    O654    A1
# 3: W123    U341    A1
# 4: W123    Y654    A1
# 5: W124    764F    A2
# 6: W124    I65F    A2
# 7: W124    O654    A2
# 8: W124    y234    A2
# 9: W125    764F    A3
# 10: W125    U341    A3
# 11: W125    Y654    A3
# 12: W125    y234    A3
```

**OLD:**

For this particular example a simple solution could be:

```
# create dataframes
df1 <- data.frame(GROUP = c("A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6","B1","B2","B3","B4","B5"),
    "CrossRef" = c(rep("W123",6), rep("W124",5)), stringsAsFactors=F)

df2 <- data.frame(Key = c(rep("W123",6), rep("W124",5)), 
                  Product = c("y234", "764F","Y654","U341","I65F","O654",
                              "342","Y6TR","HR34","QW12","675R"), stringsAsFactors=F)

# Create another dataframe with 2 values of Keys column switched
df3 <- df2
df3$Key <- ifelse(df3$Key == "W123", "W124", "W123")

# merge
merge(df1, df3,  by.x ="CrossRef", by.y = "Key", all = TRUE)

#    CrossRef GROUP Product
# 1      W123    A1    HR34
# 2      W123    A1    QW12
# 3      W123    A1     342
# 4      W123    A1    Y6TR
# 5      W123    A1    675R
# 6      W123    A2    HR34
# 7      W123    A2    QW12
# 8      W123    A2     342
# 9      W123    A2    Y6TR
# 10     W123    A2    675R
# 11     W123    A3    HR34
# ...
```

In general (if you have more than 2 values of Cross Ref values) this is not so simple, but the idea is similar - permute your second dataset.

Here is a very basic solution:

```
df12 <- data.frame(GROUP = c("A1","A2","A3"),
                  CrossRef = c("W123", "W124", "W125"), 
                  stringsAsFactors=F)
df22 <- data.frame(Key = c(rep("W123", 2), rep("W124",2), rep("W125",2)), 
                   Product = c("y234", "764F","Y654","U341","I65F","O654"), 
                   stringsAsFactors=F)

library(data.table)
df32 <- list()
i = 1
for (ikey in unique(df22$Key)){
  df32[[i]] <-cbind(Key = ikey, Product = df22$Product[df22$Key != ikey])
  i <- i+1
}
df32<- rbindlist(lapply(df32, as.data.frame))
merge(df12, df32,  by.x ="CrossRef", by.y = "Key", all = TRUE)
#    CrossRef GROUP Product
# 1      W123    A1    Y654
# 2      W123    A1    U341
# 3      W123    A1    I65F
# 4      W123    A1    O654
# 5      W124    A2    y234
# 6      W124    A2    764F
# 7      W124    A2    I65F
# 8      W124    A2    O654
# 9      W125    A3    y234
# 10     W125    A3    764F
# 11     W125    A3    Y654
# 12     W125    A3    U341
```

Comment: @Katia..I am getting this error while running this on my original file..Error in unique.default(X[[i]], ...) : unique() applies only to vectors

Comment: @Frank..I am running the code u gave it is giving me this error on my actual dataset.. Error in unique.default(X[[i]], ...) : unique() applies only to vectors

Comment: @c_174 Could you run str() and summary() on the datasets you are using. Are they data. tables? Are their any missing values? Also, are there other columns?

Comment: @c_174 Do you give the same error when you run Frank's solution and my old solution (on the bottom of the answer)?

Comment: @katia..I only run the frank solution  as the output shown in sample is not complete as discussed with frank...but his solution was giving me right answer when i tried on small data but now i am not understanding why this error pops up

Comment: @katia..I have shown the str() and summary() in edits

Comment: @c_174 One more question: How many unique values of Key and CrossRef you have in each data.table and are their values in Key column that are not in CrossRef and vice versa. Also when I asked you to check my "old" solution I meant the one that I provide in the second part of my answer after the words "Here is a very basic solution" . It actually should handle cases when Key and CrossRef have values that are not in the intersection of them. Please try and let me know if it works.

Comment: @c_174. I found why you get an error. You use lowercase key, while the column name is uppercase. You should execute: Result <- DF2[, CJ(Key = Key, Product=Product, 
                   unique=TRUE)][!DF2, on=names(DF2)][DF1, on=.(Key = Cross.Ref), allow.cart = TRUE]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170803/discussion-between-c-174-and-katia).

Comment: OK. Let's discuss it there.